# ERRORS: Pillow is not insalled while pip says its insalled

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

```
C:\Users\Bittu\Desktop\blog-api\src>python manage.py makemigrations
```

> SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS: posts.Post.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because
>   Pillow is not installed.
>           HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow".

```
C:\Users\Bittu\Desktop\blog-api\src>pip install pillow
```

> Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages

Comment: try running `pip3 install pillow`

Comment: it still says requirement already satisfied.

Comment: run `python --version` and it's probably not python 3

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? If not, I can strongly recommend that you do

Comment: @tschale thankyou that worked.